# What is the difference between GPy.models.MultioutputGP and GPy.models.GPCoregioanlizedRegression?

Tags: python-3.x, gaussian-process, gpy

The GPy library given examples on multioutput GP given [here](https://github.com/SheffieldML/notebook/blob/deploy/GPy/multiple_outputs/Introduction%20to%20Multiple%20Output%20Gaussian%20Processes.ipynb).
There also exists another example within the GPy.examples.Regression module [here](https://gpy.readthedocs.io/en/deploy/_modules/GPy/examples/regression.html#multioutput_gp_with_derivative_observations).

```
"""
compares GPCoregionalizedRegression with MultioutputGP
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import GPy


f = lambda x: np.sin(x) + 0.1 * (x - 2.0) ** 2 - 0.005 * x ** 3
fd = lambda x: np.cos(x) + 0.2 * (x - 2.0) - 0.015 * x ** 2
N = 10  # Number of observations
M = 10  # Number of derivative observations
Npred = 100  # Number of prediction points
sigma = 0.05  # Noise of observations
sigma_der = 0.05  # Noise of derivative observations
x = np.array([np.linspace(1, 10, N)]).T
y = f(x) + np.array(sigma * np.random.normal(0, 1, (N, 1)))

xd = np.array([np.linspace(2, 8, M)]).T
yd = fd(xd) + np.array(sigma_der * np.random.normal(0, 1, (M, 1)))

xpred = np.array([np.linspace(0, 11, Npred)]).T
ypred_true = f(xpred)
ydpred_true = fd(xpred)

# squared exponential kernel:
se = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=1, lengthscale=1.5, variance=0.2)
# We need to generate separate kernel for the derivative observations and give the created kernel as an input:
se_der = GPy.kern.DiffKern(se, 0)

# Then
gauss = GPy.likelihoods.Gaussian(variance=sigma ** 2)
gauss_der = GPy.likelihoods.Gaussian(variance=sigma_der ** 2)

# Then create the model, we give everything in lists, the order of the inputs indicates the order of the outputs
# Now we have the regular observations first and derivative observations second, meaning that the kernels and
# the likelihoods must follow the same order. Crosscovariances are automatically taken care of
m = GPy.models.MultioutputGP(
    X_list=[x, xd],
    Y_list=[y, yd],
    kernel_list=[se, se_der],
    likelihood_list=[gauss, gauss])


# Optimize the model
m.optimize(optimizer="lbfgs",messages=True,max_f_eval = 1000)

#%% CoregionalizedRegression on the same data, using the same kernel

K=GPy.kern.RBF(1, lengthscale=1.5, variance=0.2)
kicm = GPy.util.multioutput.ICM(input_dim=1,num_outputs=2,kernel=K)
mcoreg = GPy.models.GPCoregionalizedRegression(X_list = [x, xd], 
                                               Y_list = [y, yd], 
                                               kernel = kicm)
mcoreg.optimize(optimizer="lbfgs",messages=True,max_f_eval = 1000)

# # making predictions for the values:
# mu, var = m.predict_noiseless(Xnew=[xpred, np.empty((0, 1))])

# Two separate results!!!
m.param_array 
mcoreg.param_array
```

I wrote an MWE comparing the two using the module mentioned above.
The model parameters obtained from the two models are different. I am unsure which one should be used, if a MultiOutput model is to be built. Or rather, when to use either?